# Updated code on production server, but no changes on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I just deployed, and everything ran fine without errors. Previously it was running fine too. The code in the production is updated in the `current` version, but when I browse using a new browser, it was using old code.

I have tried restarting unicorn, nginx, but no problem whatsoever. There's no error message.

I tried it on staging environment, everything is good. Just doesn't work on production.

I tried to redeploy too. Nothing changed.

**UPDATE 1**

Not sure what happened, but after restarting the entire server it went fine again. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you use cache in your project? Maybe it is related.

Comment: No. Already run `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

Comment: I think the question was with regards to caching within your application itself (your models/views), which would be unaffected by restarting your server.

Comment: What should I do then? I even tried to hardcore some text to it and no changes reflected.

Comment: Do the changes show up once you restart your nginx at all?

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

> cd /opt/nginx/cache

and do `rm -rf *`

and restart the server again

let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cd <project dir>
rm -rf tmp/cache
apache2ctl restart
```

My situation, no changes in my controllers, or helpers were being reflected in production. This fixed it.

Also, make sure you are not running Spring in production.

```
ps aux | grep -i spring
killall spring
spring stop
```

Refer to 'Deployment', on the [github](https://github.com/rails/spring)

> You must not install Spring on your production environment. To prevent
>   it from being installed, provide the --without development test
>   argument to the bundle install command which is used to install gems
>   on your production machines:
>
> $ bundle install --without development test